# How to avoid repeating base class constructor parameters in derived class in C++?

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor

I have the following hierarchy of class:

```
 class Human {
  void foo()=0; //abstract
  int age;
  bool sex;
  double size;
  Human(int pAge,bool pSex,double pSize) : age(pAge), sex(pSex), size(pSize)     
}

class MetaHuman : Human { //abstract
 double power;
 bool fly;
 bool heal;
 MetaHuman(int pAge,bool pSex,double pSize,double pPower,bool pFly,bool pHeal) : Human(...), power(pPower),fly(pFly),heal(pHeal) }

 class SuperHuman : MetaHuman {
  void foo() const {}; //non abstract
  bool xray;
  bool inspace;
  double teleportation;
  SuperHuman(int pAge,bool pSex,double pSize,double pPower,bool pFly,bool pHeal,bool pXray,bool pInspace,double pTeleportation) : 
  MetaHuman(...),xray(pXray),inspace(pInspace),teleportation(pTeleportation) 
 }
```

As you can see i just repeat all parameters of the base class constructor down in each derived class and add couple parameters relative to the derived class.

Is there any way/pattern/design to avoid having to rewrite everything like this ?

Comment: Using a pod struct for those parameters perhaps?

Comment: Create a struct `MetaHumanData`.

Comment: Ok, seems easy enough. Thks

Comment: Check out the Named Parameters Idiom in the C++ FAQ Lite.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When it comes to strict OOP, such issues are usually handled by encapsulating the parameters in structs:

```
struct HumanData {
    int pAge, 
    bool pSex,
    double pSize,
    double pPower,
    bool pFly,
    bool pHeal
}
```

Alternatively, you could make a construct to create a SuperHuman on a MetaHuman base.

Just a hint, as I see you're trying some game dev.
Usually wrapping attributes in structures, 'pays off a lot'.
So make your SEX a bool based enum (i know, a little bit overkill :)). You can read about based class enums in C++0x here: https://smartbear.com/blog/closer-to-perfection-get-to-know-c11-scoped-and-ba/?feed=develop

You will get extra strongly typed class data, with almost no performance impact.

As a side note: Are you absolutely sure you need to make your class hierarchy so steep? As Stroustrup said "Don’t immediately invent a unique base for all of your classes. Typically, you can do better without it for many/most classes." -  which is quite accurate.

C++ is not C#/Java - forcing it to be so, will only make it rebel.

Comment: Thks for mention based class enum.

Answer (score 1):

If your problem is the sheer number of parameters, you can reduce then with structs. 
Create a struct called *humanData* which has fields like age, sex, and ask the rest. Then the constructor of the derived will look like so :

```
MetaHuman(humanData, metaHumanData)
```

If you like this and want to take it one step further, you might even make humanData a member in metaHumanData.

Answer (score 0):

You, in fact, need those values to completely define a SuperHuman. If you want to create more Superhumans based on same MetaHuman, you could create a default MetaHuman, implement copy constructor in MetaHuman (thing that you should to anyway), and then do something like

```
SuperHuman(specific parameters) : MetaHuman(normalHuman), xray(...), etc
```

or

```
SuperHuman(MetaHuman normalHumanBeforeMutation, <specific params>): MetaHuman(normalHumanBeforeMutation), ...
```

Comment: sorry, i forgot to mention human and metahuman are abstract, i just updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is no.

If you want to be able to create a `SuperHuman` with `xray` and `sex` then you must be able to pass both of those into the constructor.

There are two options available to you though if limiting your constructor arguments is very important:

```
 SuperHuman(int pAge = 0, bool pSex = false, double pSize = 0.0, double pPower = 0.0, bool pFly = false, bool pHeal = false, bool pXray = false, bool pInspace = false, double pTeleportation = 0.0)
```

Defaulting your constructor will mean you only need to pass in the arguments up to the last non-default argument you want to send so:

```
SuperHuman SuperMan(29, true, 225, numeric_limits<double>::infinity(), true, true, true); //pInspace = false and pTeleportation = 0.0
```

You can also create a constructor that takes the parent object and default all the other values for later initialization:

```
SuperHuman(const MetaHuman& pMetaHuman) : MetaHuman(pMetaHuman), xray(false), inspace(false), teleportation(0.0){}
```

Be aware that this second method means that you probably couldn't have `const SuperHuman`s with that constructor.